# How can a canvas app redirect to another tab such as the Wall?

Tags: facebook-iframe

I'm trying to create a so-called "Welcome Tab" app for a business page. What I want to happen is that either my canvas app displays a message when a vistor hasn't Liked the page, or the normal "Wall" tab when they have.

I've done this by setting my canvas page as the default landing tab and then checking the 'liked' parameter passed by Facebook and my PHP can successfully deterime what it should be doing. As per this extract:

```
if ($results['page']['liked'] == 1) {
$redirect = $pages[$results['page']['id']]['liked']; } else {

$redirect = $pages[$results['page']['id']]['unliked']; }

header('Location: '.$baseurl.$redirect);
```

However using header() to load a page which in turn contains a little bit of Javascript to do a "top.location = http://www.facebook.com/pages/xxxxxxx/yyyyyyy?sk=wall" redirection takes a second or so and results in the visitor seeing a blank canvas page briefly and then a full page reload.

However this page https://www.facebook.com/ourcarnoustie seems to be able to instantly display the Wall to Likers, and its own "Welcome" tab to non-Likers without any apparent delay or refresh.

Any suggestions or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook defaults to the wall for people who've liked the page.  In fact it's usually the reverse that's requested on how to set the welcome page for everyone :)

For what you're asking you shouldn't need to do anything as that's the behavior.

Comment: Hi Dustin and thanks. I've actually set my "Welcome" page to be the default landing page rather than the Wall - so everyone gets taken there first. My code then checks if the visitor is a Liker, and if so redirects to the Wall as I described above - but it's no where near as smooth as the example page I gave.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm this is funny you posted this cause I've just landed myself with the same issue today.

I'm using this php currently to change my html between 'liked' and 'not liked...

```
<?php
    $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];
    list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2);
    $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);
    if (empty($data["page"]["liked"])) {

//echo 'UNLIKED';

    } else {

//echo 'USER HAS LIKED';

    }
?>
```

But I also need to find away some how for the users that have already liked the page, to be redirect to the wall - instead of seeing the welcome app.

Because it's inside an iframe, do you think it's possible?

I also looked at that facebook page with welcome app that you said works, and it does work so must be possible unless its an older app that's not using a iframe to pull in the content.

Comment: Hi - yeah I did wonder if that example page I gave was using something older!  By outputing "liked" HTML within the iFrame which includes Javascript using the top.location="Full URL for Wall Page" I can certinally get it to redirect those who have Liked the page to the wall, but the problem is the canvas page displays first for a few seconds, then the entire Facebook page reloads to get the wall displayed - not very tidy and also slow :(

Comment: I did wonder if a redirect would cause a flash and in fact loading the page twice. Like you said not a tidy method. Though I will be intrigued if this can be done as I would like the same to happen on my app - good luck, I'll keep hunting too..

Comment: Hi David, you know you mentioned in your reply "I can certinally get it to redirect those who have Liked the page to the wall" - do you think you could possible help me with that code, as I need to get a tab to redirect to a website outside of facebook. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer to my own question.

The Facebook Pages FAQ includes this statement:

> Why can't I choose a landing tab for existing followers of my Page?
>
> The default landing tab can only be adjusted for people that are not following your Page. Once they follow your Page, they will see the Page's wall as the default.

So people who LIKE the page are automatically taken to the Wall page regardless of the landing tab selected in the Page settings. Therefore the landing tab app doesn't have to do any of the redirection I have been trying to figure out as Facebook already does it anyway!